# After importing into eclipse using eGit, can't compile and run. What do I do?

Tags: java, eclipse

After importing a standard .java file into Eclipse using Git, I tried to compile and run the  file. Eclipse gave me this error:

```
"Unable to launch: The selection cannot be launched, and there are no recent launches."
```

What do I do?

Comment: You didn't say if you imported a java file into an existing eclipse java project, or if you're trying to import java source from a git reop with no eclipse project information.

Comment: Oh okay. I think you need to make sure that the folder the Java source files are in is designated as a source folder in the project settings.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You must make sure your java code is in a java project.  If the git source builds from ant, there is a "File>New>Other..>Java project from ant build file".

Otherwise you need to create a java project in eclipse and then 1) import the source into the **proj**/src directory or 2) create a linked folder in eclipse that points to the source location on the file system.

Then you need to set up the classpath (add any jars that are needed for the compile).

Comment: Thanks. This is what I eventually did.

Answer (score 0):

Not really git-related, I don't think. You just need to tell it which file to run. Right click on the file with the main() function in it, and click "Run As..." > Java Application

Comment: Thanks, but there isn't that option. Just the option to add run configurations, which confuses the hell of me -- there must be a better way.

Answer (score 0):

In the last screen of the Eclipse "Clone Git Repository" wizard, make sure 
"Import all existing Eclipse projects after clone finishes" is checked.

(Perhaps this option was not available 4 years ago when the question was posted.)